# Django lock rows for atomic insertions

Tags: python, django

We are using Django 1.3. Our models are:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-ts','snp_number',)

    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    description = models.TextField()
    release = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stream = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Snap(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-snp',)
        unique_together = ('snp','app_name')

    snp = models.ForeignKey(SnapInfo)
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent_app_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Env(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-snp',)

    snp = models.ForeignKey(Snap)
    env = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Connection(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-snp',)

    snp = models.ForeignKey(Snap)
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

For a given `Info` we can have multiple `Snap`s. For a given `Snap` we can have multiple `Connection` and `Env`.

**The Write**

Somewhere in our app, we have the creation of the snaps at

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def create_snap_controller (topo_id=None, release=None, type=PREP, is_live=False):

    try:
        snp_info = Info.get_or_create_snap(release_name, type)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("%s - Error creating snap Info for the release %s and type %s " %(str(e), release_name, type))
    ...
    return create_snap(snp_info, app_name, parent_name)

def create_snap(info, app_name, parent_name):
    ...
    snp = Snap.objects.create(snp=info, app_name=app_name, parent_app_name=parent_name)

    for conn in connections:
        conn = Connection.objects.create(snp=snp, app_name=conn)
    for env in envs:
        create_env(snp, env)
    ...
    return snp

def create_env(snp, env):
    ....
    e = Env.objects.create(snp=snp, env=env)
```

**The Read**

There is also an API which reads these latest `Snap` and given `app_name` and returns JSON of itself and all associated `Env` and `Connection`.

**The concurrency issue**

The issue is sometimes the API returns partial data because the commit is not complete. That is when the API is when the commit is in progress, it returns the partial latest information.

We want to make insertions atomic, so that the reads via the API do not contain partial information.

**Efforts so far**

`select_for_update` (from 1.4 onwards) seems to lock rows but does not ensure atomicity. `transaction.commit_on_success` does not ensure atomicity either. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the database you're using.

Comment: by upgrading to a version of django that was written in this decade?

Comment: upgrading is not a solution for now. And we writing to oracle SQL.